# What is the use of --driver-class-path in the spark command?

Tags: apache-spark

As per spark [docs](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#jdbc-to-other-databases),

> To get started you will need to include the JDBC driver for you particular database on the spark classpath. For example, to connect to postgres from the Spark Shell you would run the following command:

```
bin/spark-shell --driver-class-path postgresql-9.4.1207.jar --jars postgresql-9.4.1207.jar
```

**Job is working fine without `--driver-class-path`**. Then, what is the use of `--driver-class-path` in the spark command?

Comment: `--driver-class-path` flag is Driver specific, while `--jars` flag distributes and adds the JARs to Driver's and Executors' CP.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`--driver-class-path` or `spark.driver.extraClassPath` can be used for to modify class path only for the Spark driver. This is useful for libraries which are not required by the executors (for example any code that is used only locally).

Compared to that, `--jars` or `spark.jars` will not only add jars to both driver and executor classpath, but also distribute archives over the cluster. If particular jar is used only by the driver this is unnecessary overhead.

Comment: Do you know if --packages provide the jars to the executors and the driver, or only to the executors?

Comment: @ashic Should provide on both, though not necessarily modify classpath.

Comment: if I understand well --jars is a superset of --driver-class-path, but in my case on spark 2.4.3 if I only use --jars I get a `No suitable driver` exception. If I use both --jars and --driver-class-path all runs fine.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. May I ask what is the SparkConf() equivalent of the CLI --jars? Could you provide a link? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Let's say we run the following command with Spark 3.3.0:

```
spark-submit --driver-class-path DCP.jar --jars JARS.jar MAIN.jar
```

What the scripts will actually execute is:

```
java
  -cp DCP.jar:spark/conf:spark/jars/*
  org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit
  --conf spark.driver.extraClassPath=DCP.jar
  --jars JARS.jar
  MAIN.jar
```

(I've removed the irrelevant bits.)

The surprise (for me) is that only `DCP.jar` is on the classpath. Neither `JARS.jar` nor `MAIN.jar` are on the JVM classpath. This means any JDBC driver registration from those jars will not be activated. You need to put the JDBC jar on `--driver-class-path`.

But you also want the workers to be able to do JDBC. So you need to put the JDBC jar on `--jars` too. Both are required, like the documentation says.