# PySpark SparkConf() equivalent of spark command option "--jars"

Tags: java, apache-spark, pyspark

I'd like to run some PySpark script on JupyterLab, and create custom UDF from JAR packages. To do so I need to broadcast these JAR packages to executor nodes. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43257324/what-is-the-use-of-driver-class-path-in-the-spark-command/43257577#comment126921566_43257577) has showed the command line interface approach (invoking `--jars` option in `spark-submit`). But I'd like to know the `SparkConf()` approach. On my JupyterLab `sc.version=3.3.0-SNAPSHOT`.

I'm very new to Spark.. your help will be highly appreciated!

Code:

```py
import findspark
findspark.init()
findspark.find()
import pyspark

from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import os 

# ------------ create spark session ------------
app_name = 'PySpark_Example'
path = os.getcwd()

conf = SparkConf().setAppName(os.environ.get('JUPYTERHUB_USER').replace(" ", "") + "_" + app_name).setMaster(
    'spark://spark-master-svc.spark:7077')
command = os.popen("hostname -i")
hostname = command.read().split("\n")[0]
command.close()

conf.set("spark.scheduler.mode","FAIR")
conf.set("spark.deployMode","client")
conf.set("spark.driver.host",hostname)
conf.set('spark.extraListeners','sparkmonitor.listener.JupyterSparkMonitorListener')
conf.set("spark.jars", "{path}/my_func.jar,{path}/javabuilder.jar".format(path=path))
conf.set("spark.executor.extraClassPath", "{path}/".format(path=path))

sc = pyspark.SparkContext(conf=conf)
spark = SparkSession(sc)

spark._jsc.addJar("{}/my_func.jar".format(path))
spark._jsc.addJar("{}/javabuilder.jar".format(path))

# ------------- create sample dataframe ---------
sdf = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        (1, 2.),
        (2, 3.),
        (3, 5.),
    ],
    ["col1", "col2"]
)
sdf.createOrReplaceTempView("temp_table")

# -------------- create UDF ----------------------
create_udf_from_jar = "CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_func AS 'my_func.Class1' " + \
"USING JAR '{}/my_func.jar'".format(path)
spark.sql(create_udf_from_jar)
spark.sql("SHOW USER FUNCTIONS").show()

# -------------- test ----------------------------
spark.sql("SELECT my_func(col1) FROM temp_table").show()
```

Error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
~tmp/ipykernel_4398/644670379.py in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 spark.sql("SELECT my_func(col1) FROM temp_table").show()

~opt/spark/python/pyspark/sql/session.py in sql(self, sqlQuery, **kwargs)
   1033             sqlQuery = formatter.format(sqlQuery, **kwargs)
   1034         try:
-> 1035             return DataFrame(self._jsparkSession.sql(sqlQuery), self._wrapped)
   1036         finally:
   1037             if len(kwargs) > 0:

~opt/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.3-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1319 
   1320         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
-> 1321         return_value = get_return_value(
   1322             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1323 

~opt/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
    188     def deco(*a: Any, **kw: Any) -> Any:
    189         try:
--> 190             return f(*a, **kw)
    191         except Py4JJavaError as e:
    192             converted = convert_exception(e.java_exception)

~opt/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.3-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    324             value = OUTPUT_CONVERTER[type](answer[2:], gateway_client)
    325             if answer[1] == REFERENCE_TYPE:
--> 326                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    327                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
    328                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o3813.sql.
: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mathworks/toolbox/javabuilder/internal/MWComponentInstance
```

Comment: See that green check mark in the correct [and only] answer? You get extra karma for clicking on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`spark.jars` is the one you're looking for ([Doc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html))

Comment: Thank you sir @pltc. I've tried `conf.set("spark.jars", "path/jar1.jar,path/jar2.jar")`. But when I create UDF it still complains "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: qualified/path/my_class" where qualified/path/my_class is the class in one of the jars. Do you know what might be the reason?

Comment: have you use absolute path?

Comment: Yes. I used the path from pwd..

Comment: Please post a minimal reproducable code

Comment: Thank you. I've posted a minimal reproducable code and the error. The `javabuilder.jar` can be found at `$MATLABROOT\toolbox\javabuilder\jar\javabuilder`; the `my_func.jar` is obtained by creating a simple function ```function results = my_func(inputs)
results = sum(inputs)``` in Matlab and build as a jar file: APPS -> down arrow in the far right -> Application Deployment -> Library Compiler -> Java Package.